# Add int and Class objects

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to add a int and class together like 1 + Currency(1)
I get the error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Currency'

If I do Currency(1) + 1 it works correctly.

Is there some way to convert the int into a class object or do I need to convert the class to an int object?

```
class Currency:
    "A general currency class"  
    def __init__(self, kr=0, ore=0):
        "Input kr and ore, with default values 0"
        self.ore = round(ore + (kr * 100), 0)
        self.kr = int(self.ore / 100)
        kr_ore = kr + ore / 100

    def __add__(self, other):
        self, other = Currency.__check_type(self, other)
        print(type(self), type(other))

        total = self.ore + other.ore
        self.kr = int(total / 100)
        self.ore = total - self.kr * 100

        return Currency(self.kr, self.ore)

    def __check_type(self, other):
        if type(self) != Currency and type(int) != Currency:
            self = Currency(self)
            other = Currency(other)

        elif type(self) != Currency:
            print("RUNNING")
            self = Currency(self)

        elif type(other) != Currency:
            other = Currency(other)
        return self, other

    __repr__ = __str__

x = 100
y = Currency(1)
print(x+y)
```

Comment: Why are u returning the class itself in `__add__` -> `return Currency(self.kr, self.ore)` . I think it's already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839735/add-to-custom-class-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost did it, if you printed `y+x` it would work for your code.

`__add__` is called for objects on the left side of the `+` operator, for right side, the dunder method is called [`__radd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__).

```py
class Currency:
    "A general currency class"

    def __init__(self, kr=0, ore=0):
        "Input kr and ore, with default values 0"

        self.ore = round(ore + (kr * 100), 0)
        self.kr = int(self.ore / 100)
        kr_ore = kr + ore / 100

    def __add__(self, other):
        self, other = Currency.__check_type(self, other)
        print(type(self), type(other))
        total = self.ore + other.ore
        self.kr = int(total / 100)
        self.ore = total - self.kr * 100

    def __radd__(self, other):
        self, other = Currency.__check_type(self, other)
        print(type(self), type(other))
        total = self.ore + other.ore
        self.kr = int(total / 100)
        self.ore = total - self.kr * 100
        return Currency(self.kr, self.ore)

    def __check_type(self, other):
        if type(self) != Currency and type(int) != Currency:
            self = Currency(self)
            other = Currency(other)
        elif type(self) != Currency:
            print("RUNNING")
            self = Currency(self)
        elif type(other) != Currency:
            other = Currency(other)
        return self, other

x = 100
y = Currency(1)
print(x+y)
```