# How to overload operator with first argument being built-in type?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can I overload operator with the first argument being a built-in type? For example, I have a variable class:

```py
class Variable:
    def __init__(self, value):       
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.value + other.value
        elif isinstance(other, (int, float, complex)):
            return self.value + other
        else:
            raise ValueError('Wrong data type')
```

I can do this:

```
>>> x = Variable(3)
>>> y = Variable(4)
>>> x + y
7
>>> x + 1
4
```

But I can't change the order:

```
>>> 1 + x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    1 + x
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Variable'
```

Is it possible to make this work?

Comment: Duplicate of [Add to custom class in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839735/add-to-custom-class-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding another magic method `__radd__`:

```
class Variable:
    def __init__(self, value):       
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.value + other.value
        elif isinstance(other, (int, float, complex)):
            return self.value + other
        else:
            raise ValueError('Wrong data type')
    def __radd__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.value + other.value
        elif isinstance(other, (int, float, complex)):
            return self.value + other
        else:
            raise ValueError('Wrong data type')

x = Variable(3)
print(1 + x)
```

This `__radd__` magic method is short for *reverse add*, it is for specifying what do when this class is being added to something else.